# Batch - Starting .exe A and B, after closing C end B

Tags: batch-file

So I have that batch that starts the .exe A and B, where A is a (game) launcher that closes and starts a file C. Can I make it so after I close the game (C) the B file closes aswell?

Also I have tried to get together something like this -

```
@echo off
start A.exe
start B.exe
:CheckAgain
tasklist | findstr "TheCProgram.exe"
if errorlevel 1 (timeout /T 2 & goto :CheckAgain)
taskkill B.exe
exit
```

Which doesn't work...

<strike>(Sorry for the poor terminology and typos and everything I'm such a noob when it comes to these things... And I'm so lost T.T)</strike>

Comment: `/wait` is not a command by itself.  It is an option to the `START` command.

Comment: `Sleep` is also not a standard command, you may be better advised to enter the following into a **Command Prompt** window to find out more. `Start /?`, `Timeout /?`, `TaskKill /?`. Once you've understood how those commands work, update your script above, editing the post as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for that! I think I kinda understand now that I can't use the start command, right? How do I then make the script wait for the exe (not started by the batch)?

Comment: Use TASKLIST to see if the program is running.  Create a loop to check it every minute.  When you finally do not see it running then use taskkill to stop b.exe.

Comment: @Squashman
How exactly can I do that? Again, I'm complete newcomer to batch, I started using it like 3 days ago.

Could it work like this? -
`if tasklist /FI "Services eq B.exe" /FI "Status eq running" than timeout /T 60 /NOBREAK
 else taskkill "" "C.exe"`

If so (and I don't really expect it does), how do I loop it till the `else` and than brake loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple loop that should do it:

```
:CheckAgain
tasklist | findstr "TheCProgram.exe"
if errorlevel 1 (timeout /T 2 & goto :CheckAgain)
```

Broken down:

```
:CheckAgain                :: A label for the start of the loop
tasklist                   :: Get list of running programs
findstr "TheCProgram.exe"  :: Search to see if the program C is running?
if errorlevel 1            :: If there was an error, then the program is not yet running.
timeout /T 2               :: Wait 2 seconds
& goto :CheckAgain         :: Go start the loop again to look for the program.
```

*(lightly tested, may not be rock-solid)*

---

Here is the sample script I used,

```
@echo off

:CheckAgain
tasklist | findstr "calc.exe"
if errorlevel 1 (timeout /T 2 & goto :CheckAgain)

echo The Calculator Program is now running.
```

It checks for the standard windows calculator `calc.exe`, which is easy to start.  I start the batch file in a `cmd`, then after it times out 2 or 3 times, I start the calculator.  The batch file properly detects that `calc` is running, and ends the batchfile.

Comment: *Edit* So I tried it few times and it keeps looping, no matter if "TheCProgram.exe" is running or turned off